# How to parse logentries log with goaccess?

Tags: logging, logentries, goaccess

I am having logs of all servers on logentries and when I try to open it with goaccess it gives me wrong statistics.
Is there a way through I can parse logentries log with goaccess.
I am trying to parse logentries log to goaccess. I am trying to change the log format in goaccess.conf, but not able to find correct logs.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: i get  `Total Requests  3508902 Unique Visitors 0 Referrers    0 Log Size  593.62 MiB
  Failed Requests 3508903 Unique Files    0 Unique 404   0 Bandwidth 0.0   B
  Generation Time 2       Excl. IP Hits   0 Static Files 0 Log File  XXXXXXX`

Comment: Please update your question with more details such as configuration file, and how you are running it. Seems like your log format does not match your log.

Comment: `<14>1 2015-05-12T05:04:05.814315Z ip-10-0-1-170 Nginx-Access-Log - - - hostname=xxxxxx appname=Nginx-Access-Log 10.0.1.248 - - [12/May/2015:10:34:05 +0530] "GET /rest/getShowsList?start=0&limit=15 HTTP/1.1" 200 5653 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; GT-I9060I Build/KTU84P)"
<14>1 2015-05-12T05:04:05.814339Z ip-10-0-1-170 Nginx-Access-Log - - - hostname=xxxxxxx appname=Nginx-Access-Log 10.0.1.248 - - [12/May/2015:10:34:05 +0530] "GET /rest/getexclusivedevicestatus HTTP/1.1" 200 55 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.3; D5322 Build/19.1.1.C.0.56)"
`

Comment: these are the logentries log. now i want correct log format for goaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following to the config file, works with the two lines you posted above:

```
log-format %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %^ %h %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
log-date %d/%b/%Y
log-time %H:%M:%S
```

then just run goaccess as:

```
goaccess -f access.log -p /path/to/goaccess.conf
```

Make sure you are running v0.9 though.

Comment: thnks its working fine i have posted an alternate answer too. Kayla have a look to that too.

Answer (score 0):

alternate could be that 
goaccess -f /path/to/log -a >report.html
after converting logentries log to nginx log format.